# Expanding the boot drive in a Linux virtual machine without unmounting it

Tags: linux, fdisk

I wanted to know if I can expand the boot drive of a Linux machine (`/dev/sda1`) without unmounting it or without using any external tools (like bootable live CD or GParted disk).

I basically have a Linux VM (in VMware Workstation). It by default has 34 GB space which is almost filled (hence cannot load any external hard drive manipulation tool). I have extended the space in the virtual machine with 30 GB of additional space and want to expand my `/dev/sda1` with this space (screenshot attached).

[image: Snapshot of file system]

Please tell me how to expand this drive.

Comment: There are several questions on this site regarding this, I believe. What research have you done and what have you tried?

Comment: You cannot modify a partition that is currently used. There is no way around that. You are using a VM, it is very easy to boot from an ISO.

Comment: @mashuptwice Thanks for your response. Pls tell me how to proceed towards expanding the partition using a live CD in VM. Since this is the first time I am using a Vm, I dont know about the procedure. The guest OS is Centos 6.5 and the Host OS is Win 7 (64 bit).  I want to use this virtual machine as it has certain software pre-loaded that I need. I am assuming that instead of a physical CD, I can use a pen-drive (my CD drive in my PC is long gone bad).

Comment: @ArvindGupta Note that there is a difference between expanding and resizing a partition. I suppose you mean resizing. You do not need to use a physical pendrive, as the hypervisor is able to emulate not only the VMs disk and CPU, but also CD drives, USB sticks, network adapters and nearly any other device. Resort to VMwares documentation on how to mount an iso file.

Comment: You should read the help section of superuser and use a search engine of your choice to try to find a solution by yourself before asking a question here. You can also [search on superuser itself, as this exact topic was already asked many times before](https://superuser.com/search?q=linux+vm+resize+partition)

Comment: Note that windows 7 is deprecated since january 2020 and does not receive any updates, including security updates, anymore. It is not safe to use and you'll also probably run into issues with applications that cannot be solved on your current operating system.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't modify mounted partitions in the way that you're describing.
Just use a bootable iso of GParted. It's your easiest and quickest option.